# Numpy arrays operators returns all white image

Tags: python, numpy

I perform a small uniform quantization algorithm on a gray image. When I do the loop myself, the image generated is as expected (n_levels different gray tones). This code is very slow as expected.

When I use numpy operators to speed up the code, I get a different result (all white image). I can't seem to find why... I presume it is a data type conversion thing, but I could not solve the issue.

Any help on this ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
for y in range(0, h):
    for x in range(0, w):
        frame_gray[y, x] = round(frame_gray[y, x] * n_levels / 255) * 255 / n_levels

# DIFFERENT RESULT THAN
np.rint(frame_gray * n_levels / 255) * 255 / n_levels
```

Comment: what do you get for
    frame_gray.dtype
?

Also, I think I see the problem.  Add the whole code so I can reproduce the error.

Comment: cvtColor fills frame_gray with uint8, which is what I expect for a gray image. After my loop dtype is still uint8. After the numpry operators however the array is float64. I am not able to work around this...

Comment: You need to include the relevant `import` statements and also your image! Why are you using 2 different usernames?

Comment: I was on an other computer and lazy me did not want to go through google security check !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the numpy operators to work like my for loops like this :

```
(np.rint((frame_gray / 255) *  n_levels)  * (255 / n_levels)).astype(np.ubyte)
```

Now I get the same result, and of course this is much much faster because numpy knows what it's doing...